# Image from Storage not displaying in markdown Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, email, markdown, storage

I am trying to send image `newsletter_1.jpg` from the storage to mailable `NewsletterMail.php` but it doesn't get displayed in the received email. The image is located in:

[image]

and this is the `NewsletterMail.php`, which tries to send a mail with the image:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewsletterMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        
        $body = '<img scr="'.storage_path('app/public/temp/newsletter_1.jpg').'">';

        \Log::info(print_r($body, true));

        return $this->markdown('emails.newsletter')->with('body', $body);
    }
}
```

The log shows a plausible image path:

```
local.INFO: <img scr="/Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/storage/app/public/temp/newsletter_1.jpg">
```

but the image does not get displayed in the received email. The storage is linked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to embed the image, not just link to it. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#inline-attachments  linking can work, but then your image must be stored in a publicly accessible place

Comment: @Snapey I've tried using `base64` before but gmail doesn't support it. Do you know by any chance if embedding would make it work in the gmail client?

Comment: It will.  The problem with your linking of the image is that you are linking to the image in the storage folder, not linking to the image in the /storage/temp/newsletter_1.jpg which is the public url